# powershell RSA encryption by supplying modulus and exponent

Tags: powershell, encryption, cryptography, rsa, azure-runbook

I was trying to do RSA encryption in my powershell script by supplying modulus and exponent and I have deployed it in azure automation runbook.

```
function Get-EncryptedString($certPass) 
{
    Write-Output "Getting Encrypted String."    

    $rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
    $parameters = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters
    $parameters.Modulus = $script:secretKey.Key.N
    $parameters.Exponent = $script:secretKey.Key.E
    $rsa.ImportParameters($parameters)    
    $byteData = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($certPass)
    $encryptedData = $rsa.Encrypt($byteData, $true)
    $result = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($encryptedData)

    Write-Output "Encrypted String retrieved: $result"

    return $result
}
```

When I am running the same , I am getting the following error

> caught exception:
>   System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception
>   calling "ImportParameters" with "1" argument(s): "Bad Data.
>
> " ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.
>
> at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportKey(SafeProvHandle
>   hCSP, Int32 keyNumber, CspProviderFlags flags, Object cspObject,
>   SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
>
> at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(RSAParameters
>   parameters)
>
> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception)
>
> at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)
>
> at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)
>
> at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)

Comment: What size is your data? On second thought, you are already crashing when importing the key parameters (feel free to mention that in your post). What values do you have for N and E?

Comment: I'm voting as off topic, without the info this question cannot be answered in my opinion.